# How to create multiple bash arrays in loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create multiple arrays and add a variable to the array

```
rando=$(echo $((1 + $RANDOM % 10)))
for num in $(seq 1 $rando)
do
        arr$num=()
        arr$num+=$num
        echo "${arr$num[@]}"
done
```

I was expecting;

- iterate through the loop a random amount of times, 1 - 10
- create a new array for each iteration
- add the "num" variable to the array
- print all elements of the array

Comment: Normally, I would point out that a series of numbered variable names should be an array, but since an array cannot contain references to other arrays, I'll point out that whatever you are trying to do, `bash` is not the right language to be doing it in. You'll be much happier working in a language with proper data structures.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure what you mean by proper data structures, what would be an example of that? I only really know bash and C, little bit of python but probably not enough to create arrays and all that. I'm trying to store x and y coordinates pretty much. Each row `y` would be a different array and the column `x` will be stored and compared with each array so I know which columns I've touched in each row.

Comment: You want a language with structures/objects and multidimensional arrays. `bash` only has arrays, and just a single dimension. It's almost as bad as programming in BASIC or Fortran from 40 years ago.

Comment: `bash` only has strings. `bash` doesn't really have an array *data structure*. It just has an array syntax for grouping a number of string-valued parameters under the same name. There's no sense of a name like `foo` as having an entire array as its value. (The main reason for an array is to allow a sequence of arbitrary strings to expand to number of separate words.)

Comment: If you write `foo=(1 2 3)`, you aren't creating a value `(1 2 3)` and assigning it to `foo`. That's really just a compact syntax for `foo[0]=1; foo[1]=2; foo[2]=3`. Each indexed name is more like a distinct variable than part of a collection. `"${foo[*]}"` expands to a single space-delimited string, and `"${foo[@]}"` expands to a series of separate words. Nothing lets `foo` expands to a single value *containing* multiple strings.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, so I should shift away from bash and C and try it in a better language that is OOP. That's what I figured but just wanted to know if there was a way to do it in a language I was familiar with, thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't need OO, although that's nice to use. You just need a language with real data structures. C is fine if you already know that. You can use an array of `struct` or a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nameref (requires `bash 4.2+`):

```
for ((num=1;num<=5;num++))
do
    declare -n arr="arr$num"                    # nameref

    arr=()
    arr+="$num"                                 # assigns value to index=0, ie, arr[0]
    arr[$num]=$((num + 10))

    echo "############## num = $num"
    typeset -p "${!arr}"

    for i in "${!arr[@]}"
    do
        echo "${!arr}[$i] = ${arr[$i]}"
    done
done
```

This generates:

```
############## num = 1
declare -a arr1=([0]="1" [1]="11")
arr1[0] = 1
arr1[1] = 11
############## num = 2
declare -a arr2=([0]="2" [2]="12")
arr2[0] = 2
arr2[2] = 12
############## num = 3
declare -a arr3=([0]="3" [3]="13")
arr3[0] = 3
arr3[3] = 13
############## num = 4
declare -a arr4=([0]="4" [4]="14")
arr4[0] = 4
arr4[4] = 14
############## num = 5
declare -a arr5=([0]="5" [5]="15")
arr5[0] = 5
arr5[5] = 15
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, what does the ! in `${!arr}` do?

Comment: `${!arr}` is an indirect rerference and refers to the nameref's value; eg, if you run `declare -n arr="arr3"` then `${!arr} == arr3`

Comment: just need to pay real close attention to how the `!` is applied ... `${!arr]` gets the nameref's value (helpful when you need to know *which* `arr?[]` array you're working with) ... while `${!arr[@]}"` gets the indices of the `arr[]` array

Comment: Demonstrating `arr+="$num"` (append to the 0th entry, making it longer if it already exists) vs `arr+=( "$num" )` (append to end, creating a 0th entry if no entries exist) is an interesting choice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the previous command is `arr=()` so we're guaranteed to be *appending* to nothing ... effectively *setting* the 0th entry; but your comment is valid ... there are a couple ways (in this particular case) to accomplish the same thing; a 3rd option: replace `arr=(); arr+="$num"` with `arr=("$num")`